# Using getchar to read in user input and create 2D matrix

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, user-input, getchar

The user is prompted to input a string.

input: `1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9`

output:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

Entries on the same row are separated by a single space. Rows are separated with a semicolon and a space. I need to use the getchar function to manually parse through the line of input so that I can create this matrix and do other operations with it.

Not even sure where to begin. I was thinking of using a loop that increments each time a semicolon is read. But I really don't know how to use getchar at all!

```
while((input1 = getchar())!= '\n')
{
    if((input1 > '0') || (input1 < '9')){
        matrixA[row][col] = input1;
        if(input1 == ' '){
        col++;
        matrixA[row][col] = input1;
    }
    if(input1 == ';'){
        matrixA[row][col]=input1;
        row++;
    }
```

edit: this code print (null)

Comment: I would start with a simpler task. Create a 1D array. Use `getchar` to fill it. Then use `printf` to show it.

Comment: A loop might be a good idea, if you want to read multiple characters. And note that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`. This is very important when you want to check for errors and end-of-file (or end-of-input in your case).

Comment: Why do you need to use `getchar()` — is that a requirement of the class exercise?  It probably isn't a good choice unless your hands are tied by your instructor, or you're sure that all the numbers will be single-digit numbers.

Comment: As to where to begin: start by defining a matrix — your variable `matrixA` is not (by any reasonable definition of the term) a matrix.  If you don't know how to do that, you need to hit the text book.

Comment: Using getchar is a requirement, and all input is assumed to be positive numbers of upto 6 digits.

Comment: Hmmm "all input is assumed to be positive numbers of upto 6 digits" and `1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9` does not quite jibe as input apparently includes digits, `;`, spaces and likely a line-feed.

Comment: So, time to get busy writing a function to read a number, and loops in `main()` to invoke your function to read the numbers.  What's trickier is how to deal with the semicolons.  If you're dealing with 3x3 matrices only, then they're superfluous — you can simply skip them (unless you're not allowed to assume that the data is perfect).  If you need to count the number of values before the first semicolon to deduce the size of the matrix, life is harder.  You've still not said anything about the scope of the problem. What you've shown will fail at the first byte of input — you have digits first.

Comment: Here is what I have after more research on using getchar: The use of the semicolons is to identify a new row. The user is not required to input the dimensions of the matrix, therefore, the spaces and semi colon in the user input identify the rows and columns. while((input1 = getchar())!= '\n')
    {
        if((input1 > '0') || (input1 < '9')){
            matrixA[row][col] = input1;
            if(input1 == ' '){
            col++;
            matrixA[row][col] = input1;
        }
        if(input1 == ';'){
            matrixA[row][col]=input1;
            row++;
        }

Comment: @RkRehm - add your code **to the end** of your question as an **edit** (do not delete any part of your existing question -- or the comments will no longer make sense). It is quite OK to **edit** and **add to** your question as you get more information.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin noted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some more refining: 
it only prints the first character that the user inputs or first two, depending on the number of inputs before the first semi colon is encountered. My print statement is outside the loop.

```
char matrixA[100][100];

char matrixB[100][100];
char input1, input2;
int row=0, col=0, num = 0;

printf("Enter matrix A:\n");

while(input1 != '\n'){

    input1 = getchar();

    if((input1 > '0') && (input1 < '9') && (input1 != ' ') && (input1 != ';')){
        //num = (num*10) + (input1 - '0');
        matrixA[row][col] = input1; 
    }  

    if(input1 == ' '){
        col++;
    }
    if (input1 == ';'){
        row++;        
    } 
}
```